# Removing default look of JButton in Swing

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

I am making an application in Java Swing and I have to use buttons there.

I have a button and I have set background image of `JButton` using `ImageIcon`. I have made this image using Photoshop When I click on the button then its default color is shown.  I am also setting background color to white but this is not solving my problem.

How to remove default color of button?

Comment: and... where's the code so we can test?

Answer (score 2):

Make your image as a button :

```
BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("MyImage"));
button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
```

and set your button like so :

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setFocusPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Comment: Thanx for reply.I have tried this code.But when I click on button its default color is displaying. What to do?